# Why is that Tornado converts all request values to list? even if it is not?

Tags: python, tornado

I started working with `tornado` recently, one thing which annoys me is its `POST` value parsing. 
 In an example ajax request if I am sending name and email as form data.

the expected data in server is

```
{ "name": "John Doe", "email": "john@doe.me"}
```

but it converts each value to a list like below

```
{"name": ["John Doe"], "email": ["john@doe.me"]}
```

Can somebody explain Why is this behavior implemented in tornado? Can't it simply return the value without converting it to a list?

Comment: webob's MultiDict does seem more elegant to me, but tornado's way you always know exactly what you're going to get, whether the POST has duplicate keys or not. You'd have to ask the developers for a real answer to "why?", though.

Comment: Ben Darnell, who is a Tornado developer, commented on A. Jesse Jiryu Davis' answer below. I would say that is the most authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just tornado - this is how the form-urlencoded format is defined. Every argument may appear multiple times and you have no way of knowing whether an argument that appears once was intended to be a single-element list or a single value. To avoid having to think about this, most of your access to the request arguments should go through RequestHandler.get_argument and RequestHandler.get_arguments to make it clear whether you expect a list or a single value.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine this is such that whether the values are lists or not they can be used in a unified way without having to then **check** if they're a list or not.

E.g. imagine you wanted to do something with `name`, but as it can sometimes be a list and sometimes a single value, every time you worked with `name` you'd have to include something like

```
if isinstance(name, list):
    # Handle the list
else:  
    # Handle a string
```

Instead, you can access `name[0]` without worrying that you might be accessing the first character of a string.

**Disclaimer**

I am *not* a Tornado developer; you'd have to ask them for the reason they went with this convention to be sure.

Comment: But don't you think forcing user to use list, will create overhead for 90% of time where you only send one value not a list?

Comment: Its possible that including internal logic within Tornado to output  *either* a string or list dependent on the input would actually be more overhead, and so they leave that logic up to the users to include if needed, though I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Tornado supports multiple values for the same parameter name:

`http://example.com/page?foo=1&foo=2`

This is parsed, obviously, as:

`{'foo': ['1', '2']}`

Tornado **could** set each value to a string if there's only one value, and a list of strings if there are multiple values. Then your code must check each value's type before using its contents. But it's far more convenient, and far less error-prone, to wrap all values in lists all the time.

Comment: It's not just tornado - this is how the form-urlencoded format is defined.  Every argument may appear multiple times and you have no way of knowing whether an argument that appears once was intended to be a single-element list or a single value.  To avoid having to think about this, most of your access to the request arguments should go through RequestHandler.get_argument and RequestHandler.get_arguments to make it clear whether you expect a list or a single value.

Comment: @BenDarnell Could you please add this as answer so that I can accept it :-)